# Dask support for CSV file with header

Tags: python, pandas, dask

It seems that `dask` does not support reading a CSV file that includes a header. When I try to read it I get

```
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can read the same file with pandas with no problem and with dask without the header, but them dask attributes the first line as the header. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) supports CSV files with headers:

```
In [1]: cat foo.csv
name,amount
alice,100
bob,200

In [2]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [3]: dd.read_csv('foo.csv').compute()
Out[3]: 
    name  amount
0  alice     100
1    bob     200
```

But generally CSV files can be tricky.  If you [raise an issue](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/new) with a sample file that fails we can track down what's going on and resolve the problem.